# What is the average cost difference per year to raise a infant before schooling?

Tags: infant, money

Bring in a new human being into the world and need to do some budgeting.

Southern California, suburb of a major city.

One income household with both parents.

Don't know who will be watching the child, depends on budget and if the other parent needs to work..

In the United State, living in a upper middle class society, what is the average cost of raising an infant, at each year (for the first 5 years before schooling starts)?

For example:

Average cost at age 1:
Average cost at age 2:
Average cost at age 3:
Average cost at age 4:
Average cost at age 5:

Comment: This is not a parenting question. It's about money and finances.

Comment: the average cost is not of use to anyone. Some people spend nothing the first year, using hand me down cloth diapers clothes, exclusively breastfeeding etc. Others have a staff of nannies from day 1 and spend hundreds of dollars on each of the baby's outfits, and thousands of dollars on professional photo shoots each month. Some buy enormous cars and say it's a baby expense. The number arrived at by averaging those people would not tell you anything valuable.

Comment: @Dariusz I disagree.  It certainly is related to parenting, and the financial aspect of parenting is on topic for this site.  While this also might be on topic at [Money.se], StackExchange philosophy allows for this possibility, and there is nothing wrong with the question being on this site.

Comment: @Erica and Chrys, why do you say the average is of no use to anyone?  It's clearly of use to some, as the USDA does an annual study to determine the values.  While I don't think this is a super-greatly worded question, I don't see why you should treat this as too broad (it's not - it has a very specific, easy to find answer) or say it's not of any use (it may not be useful for determining how much it costs to raise your future child, but it might be useful for determining appropriate AFDC levels, for example!).

Comment: @KRT While I think this is an answerable question, you would get a better response and be less likely to be closed if you included more text in the question. Particularly, why are you asking it?  Are you asking because you want to know for a research paper - that's basically what it looks like now (and is probably not a good reason to ask on this site).  Are you asking because you want to have a child, or want to not have a child, and want the information to inform that decision?  Or some other reason?

Comment: @Erica I know, I was generalizing to combine that comment into one with Chrys' (who did).  And I agree motivation is important to getting good answers.  But I also think that it's not too broad, on its face; it's a very easily answerable question as asked (albeit the answer may or may not be exactly what the asker wants).

Comment: @Joe in any case, your later comment is better phrased than my original(s) :) Nice responses.

Comment: @Joe: no research paper but to figure out how much this new human being will cost the first 5 years.

Comment: @KRT If you're trying to figure out *for yourself* then you would get better answers if you provide some additional information.  At minimum, what region of the country are you in (NorthEast, South, Midwest, West), are you in a city, a suburb of a major city, an exurb, a smaller city, or a rural environment?  Are you a two income household, a single parent, or a single earner/dual parent household?  Who will be watching the child?  The last one is super important - it's potentially over half the total expense if you have daycare expenses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the USDA's [Expenditures on Children by Families](http://www.cnpp.usda.gov/sites/default/files/expenditures_on_children_by_families/crc2013.pdf) annual study (2013 is the latest I found):

```
Table 10. Estimated annual expenditures* on a child born in 2013 by income group,
overall United States
Income group
Year Age Lowest Middle Highest
2013 <1 $9,480  $12,940 $21,430
2014 1   9,710   13,250  21,940
2015 2   9,940   13,570  22,470
2016 3   10,220  13,930  23,020
2017 4   10,470  14,260  23,570
2018 5   10,720  14,600  24,140
```

They don't provide a single value, but you could determine that by going to the [Consumer Expenditure Survey](http://www.bls.gov/cex/) and duplicating the USDA's methodology, which is included in their annual report.

They do explain that this varies significantly by income, single/double parent household, region, and other factors; many of these are broken out in the report.

Comment: I'd also note that a _big_ factor in Middle -> Highest is childcare: Middle and Lowest are likely either single-income households, not working at all, or have family or friends watching the child; at minimum, they might be using an at-home daycare center, but even then it's hard to imagine $12000 being enough in an urban environment in particular - I spend close to $12000 on one child alone at an at-home daycare (in an urban environment).  Highest are very likely using daycare centers which can be upwards of $15k per child.

Comment: Another relevant note: they specifically state that *housing* expenses are usually a significant portion if not the largest, particularly in the lower incomes; that's likely because they count most of the housing expense as due to the child - without a child people tend to have much smaller houses (or just live in an apartment) and choose less nice areas to live (particularly with lower property taxes and thus worse schools).

Comment: thanks for your wealth of information, I appreciate you help. Are you saying the day care alone was 12k a year for your child?

Comment: Daycare costs are *highly* variable.  You could write a book on the subject.  But at minimum, consider that as an infant you need a 4:1 ratio (in my state, around that in general) of infants to caregivers.  So for a minimal $12 an hour labor cost ($8+taxes and benefits), each is responsible for $3.  Say 50 hours a week, the *minimum* cost would be $150 per week or $7800 a year.  Add in the costs for facilities, foods, etc., and $12k is pretty reasonable.

Comment: Our first child was in a nicer daycare center before we moved to the suburbs; the annual cost there was about $18k.  That was for the infant room, which had 5 teachers to 12 kids (so better than 3 to 1 rate), fairly educated staff, its own building and playground, etc.

Comment: To reinforce Joe's point that location matters, our childcare cost for an infant in a comparable sounding facility was about half that ($10k) annually.

Comment: 10k is about as low as I could imagine it, assuming you're paying minimum wage, and not getting subsidies (which some do).  I worked out how much they made from the entire infant class, and they barely had reasonable salaries - under 20k per FT employee, and that assuming the owner/director didn't take much of a salary.  I know they make more from the older classes (with a higher S:T ratio), though, and perhaps that offsets the infant room some...  but the averages in the linked study don't make any sense to me (the highest 'average' 0-2 was under 6k, and that was 'of people using childcare')

Comment: I consider myself very lucky to have managed to get my daycare costs down to $750 a month for my 2 kids. Don't think that ends when they go to school. Remember most schools get out well before any normal job ends for the day.